# MVC3 - Form + POST = empty parameters

Tags: apache, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, mono, controller

I am currently working on an ASP.NET MVC3 website.

I have a simple authentication form, binded on a simple viewmodel. When debugging on local, everything works fine.

But the website has to wotk on Apache + monomod too. And here is the strange behavior I encounter: the same form, with the same requests and parameters, are nto working.

More details:

The viewmodel:

```
/// <summary>
/// Form authentication info
/// </summary>
public class LogOnModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Username")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DisplayName("Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Targeted URL
    /// </summary>
    public string Target { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    public LogOnModel()
    {
    }
}
```

The main part of the view, page where the user can enter its username and password :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Website.Areas.Public.Models.LogOnModel>" %>
<p>
    Please enter your username and password to continue.
</p>
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Authentication failed.")%>
<p>
    <%= Html.ActionLink("I forgot my password","PasswordRecovery","Home") %>
</p>
<div>
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            <%= Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)%>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password) %>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%= Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe) %>
            Remember me
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Connect me!" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
</div>
<% } %>
```

And the controller, receiving the auth infos :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {
        string username = model.UserName;
        string password = model.Password;

        //On Apache, username & password are empty
       ...
    }
```

As I say in the comments, username & password are empty. Everything is working fine on a local ASP.NET debug server, and using Fiddler I can see that the requests for authentication contains form data (username, password, etc).

Any idea why the binding seems not to be working? 
Thanks.

Comment: Hmm I can get the values using HttpContext.Request.Form["UserName"], etc... But it doesn't seems very clean to me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found my answer, many months later. It's a bit late but if anyone has the same problem, here's the solution :

**Clean the Web.config file. Delete every lines that are optionnals**

Answer (score 0):

What version of mono are you using? I ran into this issue when I first tried setting up am MVC 2 site on mono (2.4 or 2.6). I don't remember what the underlying cause was beyond it being a fairly complex mono bug/implementation difference that has since been fixed - MVC3/Razor running on mono 2.10.2 works as expected.

Comment: Well I'm using Mono 2.10.2 and MVC 3

Comment: Do you have anything in your pages that would fail if you used mvc 1 or 2? Mono assembly binding works differently to .net, so it is quite easy to get set up partly using the wrong version.

Comment: I guess not, I'm not even using the Razor view engine (still using the old one). It seems that routing is quite different on Mono than on IIS. As I only have a default route, parameteres are not matched.

Comment: Routing should be the same (that's all in the MVC assembly), but binding is different. I suggest adding some code on your page to display assembly versions and verify that you are running what you think you are.

Comment: You're right, routing is effective otherwise it wouldn't find the method... Do you know how to display those versions ? With typeof(Controller).AssemblyQualifiedName?

Comment: Something like that - type.Assembly.Version would be closer to what you want I think.

Comment: You confirmed that from within the same process that isn't working as expected? Any binding errors/warnings in the logs?